# How to insert a input present in plsql procedure in a select statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, exception, cursor

I have 2 tables, parent and child. I am making a procedure which will take id as input and give the output from both the tables. If a row is not found in table 2 it will give an exception.

For this, I used a cursor for select statement and passed it as out parameter in my procedure, but I am confused what to give condition in the cursor's select statement so that it will check the id which is provided as input and display the rows from both the tables.[screen shot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABGbf.png)

CODE:

```
    create or replace procedure stu_proc
(st_id in student_main.stu_id%type,
st_cur out sys_refcursor)
is
cursor cur_st(st_id number) is select * from student_main sm 
join student_details sd
on sm.id = sd.st_id
where sm.id = st_id;
st_id cur_st%rowtype;
begin
open cur_st;
loop
fetch cur_st into st_cur;
exit when cur_st%notfound;
end loop;
close cursor;
exception
when no_data_found then 
dbms_output.put_line('Student details not found');
end;
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Hi i have added the snapshot of my code with my question.Please suggest me the changes.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Code pictures are not helpful to the community.

Comment: Try my updated answer dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes i can join but my main concern is to join only those rows whose
>   input will be provided by user as student id(used as IN parameter in
>   the procedure)

I can see few issues with your code.

1) Passing parameters to cursor is not done, so the input value you passed is actaully not used while evaluating the cursor.

2)  This variable declaration is looking wrong `st_id cur_st%rowtype`. It should be like `st_cur cur_st%rowtype`.

Also note that since you are already using s `sys_refcursor` for retruning the result of the query, there is no need to open another explicit cursor. You code can be modified as below:

Please try below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stu_proc(
        col_st_id IN student_main.id%type,
        st_cur OUT sys_refcursor)
    IS  
    BEGIN
      OPEN st_cur for 
       SELECT sm.*
        FROM student_main sm
        JOIN student_details sd
        ON sm.id    = sd.st_id
        WHERE sm.id = col_st_id;

      EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Student details not found');
    END;
```

Comment: yes syntax error are all corrected now but after compilation it is still giving me error as: Compilation unit analysis terminated,duplicate fields in record ,table or argument list are not permitted

Comment: @Angshuman Try now. Error has come coz we had used `st_id` twice. Once as input parameter to procedure and another with same name to cursor, which is not allowed. It should work now.

Comment: @Angshuman . Apologies as i didnot see that you are returning a `sys_refcursor`. See that you dont need a cursor when you return the result using a `sys_refcursor`. See modified working code

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass the parameter to the cursor :)

```
cursor cur_st(stud_id number) is
select * from student_main sm
join student_details sd
on sm.id = sd.st_id
where sm.id = stud_id;
```

and on calling it

```
stu_proc(:stud_id, s_cur);
```

Comment: yes i can join but my main concern is to join only those rows whose input will be provided by user as student id(used as IN parameter in the procedure)

Comment: Now it is giving me error as: Compilation unit analysis terminated,duplicate fields in record ,table or argument list are not permitted

Comment: please paste the code in your question. its so hard to edit it.

Comment: dude you didnt closed the cursor

Comment: i had already closed the cursor at line 16.I think something else is the error.